# How do I use the SOQL IN keyword in the API? (C#)

Tags: soql, api, c#

I'm building something in which I get a list of parent objects, then would like to get a list of child objects whose parent account ID appears in the first list.

Normally I would do something like:

```
[SELECT Id, Parent_Object_Id__c FROM Child_Object__c WHERE Parent_Object_Id__c IN myList]
```

But I don't know what to do exactly. Do I just add my List holding all the parent IDs to the query string? Or do I need to do something else? That way doesn't seem like it would work for some reason.

Comment: This is possible if you are having a correct string of Ids

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do I need some kind of particularly formatted string? I can't imagine concatenating the list variable would work like it would in apex.

Comment: See in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building the where clause as a string in this form (for each ID you have) would work:

```
where Parent_Object_Id__c in ('0035000000nTfXe', '0035000001WH76J', '00350000024hHjG')
```

providing the resulting string is 20,000 or less characters long (the current SOQL query length limit).

Comment: Adding to this the IN :myList syntax is a feature of apex that isn't available via the API since there's no standard way of binding to a collection type without writing some code in the language calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

C# Code:

```
string myIdList = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < yourObjList; i++)
            myIdList = myIdList + "'" + yourObjList[i]["Id"].ToString().Trim() + "',";

        if (myIdList.EndsWith(","))
            myIdList = myIdList.Remove(myIdList.Length - 1, 1);
```

Then use that string in your query,

```
string query = "SELECT Id, Parent_Object_Id__c FROM Child_Object__c WHERE Parent_Object_Id__c IN (" + myIdList +" )";
```

Comment: C# has a join available for a one line solution `string s = "'" + String.Join("','", ids) + "'";`.

Comment: That's much better @KeithC . I just added this because most of the times developers miss that single quote around th id.

Comment: Good point. Made me Google a bit about C# to check that it does have some decent string methods...